# how to prove that Fibonacci sequence is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

Fibonacci sequence is defined as follows $\{F_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$, where $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$. How to prove that this sequence is divergent?

I started with definition of limit goes to infinity, i.e. $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} s.t. \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n < n_{0} \implies F_{n} > M$ , prove that it is divergent.

I have no idea how to prove it, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove (say by induction) that for $n \ge 5$, we have $F_n \ge n$?

Comment: any strictly increasing integer sequence limits to infinity.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen is it necessarily supposed to be $n \geq 5$, can it be $n \geq 3$? Since only $F_{2} and F_{3}$ are non-increasing.

Comment: @TRadept, I reckon $F_4 = 3$, so indeed $n \ge 5$ is necessary to prove $F_n \ge n$. Of course, you can also prove $F_n \ge n - 1$ for $n \ge 3$ if you like - exactly which version doesn't matter hugely.

Answer (score 2):

We prove that $F_n \geq n-2$ by induction.

(1) The inequality hold for $n=1,2,3,4$.

(2) Suppose it is true for $F_n$ with $n=1,2,...,k+1$ for $k\geq3$, then we have $F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_k \geq (k-1)+(k-2) = 2k-3 \geq k$. (The last inequality holds by $k \geq 3$).

This proves $F_n>n-2$ and hence $F_n$ diverge. Actually, Fibonacci sequence diverge exponentially, but here we only prove it diverge faster than $O(n)$.